# Creating multiple price trajectories plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I want to create a plot that shows the trajectory my data points over a span of a range of days.

Lets take this example:

1. The start date, i.e., created_at
2. The day of the final price, i.e., final_price_day
3. The difference of the two, i.e., days_to_final
4. Price i.e., price

So the plot should essentially show the price's trajectory over the days_to_final period. And since there are multiple days, I'd like to show multiple trajectories on one graph. I'm really not sure how to achieve that, `geom_segment` and `geom_curve` allow for the trajectory to be shown I think but I don't know if It'll achieve the exact result I want.

I'll attach a graph I made on paint of how plot can look like. Can this even be made?

[image: price_trajectory]

dput output:

```
structure(list(final_price_day = structure(c(18901, 18901, 18902, 
18902, 18901, 18903, 18903, 18901, 18902, 18902, 18903, 18904, 
18901, 18905, 18903, 18904, 18905, 18901, 18902, 18902, 18903, 
18904, 18905, 18901, 18906, 18907, 18902, 18903, 18904, 18905, 
18907, 18901, 18906, 18903, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18901, 
18902, 18908, 18909, 18902, 18903, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 
18909, 18901, 18908, 18910, 18902, 18903, 18904, 18905, 18906, 
18907, 18910, 18901, 18909, 18908, 18903, 18905, 18906, 18907, 
18910, 18911, 18901, 18902, 18904, 18908, 18909, 18902, 18903, 
18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18910, 18911, 18912, 18901, 18908, 
18909, 18913, 18902, 18903, 18904, 18905, 18907, 18909, 18910, 
18913, 18901, 18906, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18903, 18904, 18905, 
18906, 18909, 18910, 18911, 18912, 18901, 18902, 18907, 18908, 
18913, 18914, 18902, 18903, 18904, 18905, 18909, 18910, 18911, 
18912, 18913, 18914, 18915, 18901, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18915, 
18904, 18905, 18907, 18910, 18911, 18912, 18913, 18901, 18902, 
18903, 18906, 18916, 18908, 18909, 18914, 18915, 18904, 18906, 
18907, 18909, 18910, 18911, 18913, 18917, 18901, 18902, 18905, 
18908, 18912, 18914, 18915, 18916, 18903, 18918, 18905, 18907, 
18910, 18913, 18914, 18917, 18901, 18903, 18904, 18906, 18908, 
18909, 18911, 18915, 18916, 18918, 18902, 18912, 18902, 18903, 
18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18910, 18911, 18912, 18913, 18914, 
18901, 18909, 18915, 18916, 18917, 18918, 18908, 18919), class = "Date"), 
    created_at = structure(c(18900, 18899, 18900, 18899, 18898, 
    18900, 18899, 18897, 18898, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18896, 18900, 
    18897, 18898, 18899, 18895, 18896, 18895, 18896, 18897, 18898, 
    18894, 18899, 18900, 18894, 18895, 18896, 18897, 18899, 18893, 
    18898, 18894, 18895, 18896, 18897, 18898, 18892, 18893, 18899, 
    18900, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18895, 18896, 18897, 18899, 18891, 
    18898, 18900, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18895, 18896, 18899, 
    18890, 18898, 18897, 18891, 18893, 18894, 18895, 18898, 18899, 
    18889, 18890, 18892, 18896, 18897, 18889, 18890, 18891, 18892, 
    18893, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18888, 18895, 18896, 18900, 
    18888, 18889, 18890, 18891, 18893, 18895, 18896, 18899, 18887, 
    18892, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18888, 18889, 18890, 18891, 18894, 
    18895, 18896, 18897, 18886, 18887, 18892, 18893, 18898, 18899, 
    18886, 18887, 18888, 18889, 18893, 18894, 18895, 18896, 18897, 
    18898, 18900, 18885, 18890, 18891, 18892, 18899, 18887, 18888, 
    18890, 18893, 18894, 18895, 18896, 18884, 18885, 18886, 18889, 
    18899, 18891, 18892, 18897, 18898, 18886, 18888, 18889, 18891, 
    18892, 18893, 18895, 18899, 18883, 18884, 18887, 18890, 18894, 
    18896, 18897, 18898, 18885, 18900, 18886, 18888, 18891, 18894, 
    18895, 18898, 18882, 18884, 18885, 18887, 18889, 18890, 18892, 
    18896, 18897, 18899, 18883, 18893, 18882, 18883, 18884, 18885, 
    18886, 18887, 18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18881, 18889, 
    18895, 18896, 18897, 18898, 18888, 18899), class = "Date"), 
    price = c(10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 6810, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 6810, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    6810, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 6524, 6810, 7524, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 6524, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 6524, 6524, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 6667, 10499, 6524, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    6524, 6810, 6524, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 6524, 10499, 6524, 6524, 6524, 6524, 6220, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 6524, 10499, 10499, 10499, 
    10499, 10499, 10499, 10499), days_to_final = structure(c(1, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
    13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
    15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
    17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
    17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), class = "difftime", units = "days")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -200L), groups = structure(list(
    final_price_day = structure(c(18901, 18902, 18903, 18904, 
    18905, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18909, 18910, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
    18914, 18915, 18916, 18917, 18918, 18919), class = "Date"), 
    .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 24L, 32L, 
    39L, 50L, 60L, 69L, 83L, 95L, 108L, 125L, 137L, 154L, 170L, 
    193L), c(3L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 19L, 20L, 27L, 40L, 43L, 53L, 70L, 
    74L, 87L, 109L, 114L, 138L, 155L, 180L, 182L), c(6L, 7L, 
    11L, 15L, 21L, 28L, 34L, 44L, 54L, 63L, 75L, 88L, 100L, 115L, 
    139L, 162L, 171L, 183L), c(12L, 16L, 22L, 29L, 35L, 45L, 
    55L, 71L, 76L, 89L, 101L, 116L, 130L, 146L, 172L, 184L), 
        c(14L, 17L, 23L, 30L, 36L, 46L, 56L, 64L, 77L, 90L, 102L, 
        117L, 131L, 156L, 164L, 185L), c(25L, 33L, 37L, 47L, 
        57L, 65L, 78L, 96L, 103L, 126L, 140L, 147L, 173L, 186L
        ), c(26L, 31L, 38L, 48L, 58L, 66L, 79L, 91L, 110L, 127L, 
        132L, 148L, 165L, 187L), c(41L, 51L, 62L, 72L, 84L, 97L, 
        111L, 128L, 142L, 157L, 174L, 199L), c(42L, 49L, 61L, 
        73L, 85L, 92L, 104L, 118L, 143L, 149L, 175L, 194L), c(52L, 
        59L, 67L, 80L, 93L, 105L, 119L, 133L, 150L, 166L, 188L
        ), c(68L, 81L, 98L, 106L, 120L, 134L, 151L, 176L, 189L
        ), c(82L, 99L, 107L, 121L, 135L, 158L, 181L, 190L), c(86L, 
        94L, 112L, 122L, 136L, 152L, 167L, 191L), c(113L, 123L, 
        144L, 159L, 168L, 192L), c(124L, 129L, 145L, 160L, 177L, 
        195L), c(141L, 161L, 178L, 196L), c(153L, 169L, 197L), 
        c(163L, 179L, 198L), 200L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to make the graph on excel, not exactly the way I wanted to but is it possible to do the same thing in R? To make this dataset, I pivoted the dataset into wider format and made each `days_to_final` a column and `price` was the values in that column. Then `final_price_day` was its own column and excel sort of just made this on its own

[image: price_tj_excel]

Comment: What are the groups here? `created_at`?

Comment: @Maël As a starting point, I tried `library(tidyverse); library(ggplot2); df %>% ggplot(aes(x=final_price_day, y=price, group=created_at)) + geom_line()
`. But the resulting plot looks way off

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well. But it does not seem like the data you provided can do what you painted, almost all values are 10499; is that intended?

Comment: @ Maël, it's intended since that's how the data is behaving. If its just constant then perhaps a flat line is best suited for it?